# What is OAuth 1.0b authentication?

Tags: oauth

I heard people talk about OAuth 1.0b, but I can't find it on http://oauthbible.com/, or anywhere else on the web.

Could someone explain me how this protocol works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't an OAuth protocol with that specific "official" version number but I'm guessing one may use "b" to refer to the OAuth 1.0a version that was later standardized by the IETF as in [RFC 5849](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5849) which does contain some errata over 1.0a.